# How to edit the eTLD list in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, session-cookies, chromium, tld, public-suffix-list

I'm working with a third party website that has two subdomains. One for staging and one for production. Let's take `site1.example.tld` and `site2.example.tld`. when logging in to `site1.example.tld` The website set's the authentication cookies on the `example.tld` domain making them accessible to both subdomains. When going to `site2.example.tld` it will realize that the cookies are invalid, remove them, and force a login. Yes, this is a misconfiguration on their side but there isn't much I can do about that for now.

I recently learned about the `Public Suffix List` and how browsers use it. Adding `example.tld` as an eTLD to that list would allow me to force the browser to treat the two subdomains as separate domains and allow me to stay logged on both origins.

Is there a way to edit/override/append to that list locally in chrome or chromium based browsers?

Comment: Not sure if that info is stored in any easily accessible way, so that you could modify it without compiling the source code again yourself. (If this _was_ easy to manipulate, then I guess there would be some abuse potential by talking naive users into making certain changes ...) I think I would probably just visit the staging system in a private browser window here, to that it doesn't interfere with the cookies set in the non-private window where you are working with the prod system ..